# Multi Thread Rsync Transfer

Tags: rsync

For some reason when running a single rsync command I am getting 1 MB/sec to 2 MB/sec even when I connecting 2 servers both connected to 1 Gbps ports.

> rsync -v --progress -e ssh /backup/mysqldata/mysql-bin.000199
>   root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/secondary/mysqldata/mysqldata/mysql-bin.000199

I have over 800 GB of data to transfer split among 500 or so files all starting with:

mysql-bin.000*

I've found that running 25-30 rsync simultaneously from seperate SSH windows gets me upwards of 25 MB/sec but it will take me hours to run these all manually.

Is there anyway to get the 25 MB/sec from a single rsync command?

Comment: You might want to investigate setting up an rsync daemon, or using something other then SSH for a large transfer like that (RSH).  Are they on your local network.  Do you really need the encryption overhead?  Maybe mount the filesystem using NFS?

Comment: What's the latency to the remote host?

Comment: Latency averages 24ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenSSH is notorious for having window size limits which are not very friendly for high-latency connections.  To determine the minimum window size for your desired throughput (let's ignore other overhead for now):

```
Window size = throughput * latency
```

So, if you want 25MB/sec (200,000,000 bits/sec) over a 25ms latency (0.025 seconds):

```
Window size = 200,000,000 * 0.025 = 5000000.0 bits
```

Divided by 8, that's roughly a 625KB window.  Let's flip it around and look at a 64KB window (the internal cap in many versions of OpenSSH) at your latency:

```
throughput = 512000 bits / 0.025s latency = 20480000.0 bits/sec = ~2.5MB/sec
```

That's pretty close to what you're seeing (you may have some other overhead as well.)

So, I would check in the following order:

- Ensure your OS has its [TCP window sizes set sanely and autoscaling enabled](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/networking/641-tcp-tune).
- Make sure you are using a version of SSH without a fixed internal window size (I believe this was fixed around OpenSSH 4.7) OR install [HPN-SSH](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh), which is patched to address these issues.
- Try using lighter options for SSH (arcfour, for example)

Answer (score 0):

SSH performance can vary drastically according to whether compression is on.

Comment: could you expand on this a little please ?

Comment: If compression is on CPU time is used in an attempt to save on network bandwidth.  If the data is highly compressible this may be a net gain - or with more random-looking data it would be a net loss.  Check whether your SSH defaults to compressing and see if you get better results with the other option.